# Windows 10 freeze on startup after installing VS 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I've installed Windows 10 (release version) and after VS 2015 Community edition, rebooted, windows applied some updates, rebooted again and that's it. I see only the windows loading screen (circle) and it doesn't boot up. I've waited for 1 hour, and still nothing. 
Safe mode works. But you can't work from safe mode =)
I've searched MS forums - nothing.
Maybe somebody had this issue. Help appreciated.
Details: HP Pavilion g6, Windows 10 (fresh installation), VS 2015.

Comment: I'm experiencing almost the same. After a Windows 10 install everything works great and I can install any application without problem (and boot afterwards). But after I install VS2015 and do a reboot Windows 10 fails to boot and automatically reboots into the startup repair function. This finds nothing and I am forever stuck here. I can boot into safe mode tho. I'm using an HP EliteBook 8570w.

Comment: Hi Jelle, i've found this: [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1608843)
The point is that you have to change all you regional settings to US. I didn't try that yet, but when i do, i will post the result here.

Comment: Ran into this problem after upgrading from an insider preview build to release build 1511. Windows runs as a guest in ESXi, had no problem using hyper-v before - just had to set some CPU flags.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from HyperV that is enabled when you installed VS2015.
Boot in Safe mode then press WinKey + R then type appwiz.cpl then  click OK. Enable/Disable Windows features and uncheck Hyper-V.
Next reboot should be OK the problem is VS2015 uses HyperV for its emulators and it's very annoying to not be able to use it.
Hope microsoft will find a fix for people who face this issue.
For information I have an Asus P8Z68V-LX(Bios 4105)+i5-2500K@3.3Ghz.

Comment: In my case I was able to fix everything by enabling "Execute Disable Bit" inside my BIOS. And now I can re-enable HyperV but the original thread already mentioned by DrBigNick is the best source of information.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't due to virtualization being turned off in your bios?

Answer (score 1):

as a 70 year old with no bios knowledge, I do the old fashioned method; hold the off button till the beast shuts down and then reboot. don't know why but its working every time; just installed latest update this am still no fix, guess MS hasn't heard about the thousands of users affected yet. I'm sure they will get right on it when they do!!

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished installing Windows 10 on my daughters hp g6. It was a bit of a nightmare tbh. Tried loads of different suggestions, eventually found one that let the full installation happen. Uninstalled sound and graphics drivers, turned off windows defender and firewall and it went all the way. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Paul, I didn't have problem during or after installation of Win 10. I had problems after installing Visual Studio (VS) 2015 Community edition. Everything works before installing VS.